# Newton-Raphson with multiple root

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

To approximate the root of a function, which also happens to be of multiplicity greater than 1, how do I choose the starting point of the algorithm? For example, I am trying to approximate the root $0$ of $f(x) = e^{sin^3(x)} + x^6 - 2x^4 - x^3 - 1$ with $5$ correct decimal places yet no matter what starting point near $0$ I choose it always converges to something like $0.00009$ giving me only $4$ correct decimal places.

I know there are modified versions of the algorithm that work for multiple roots but I am interested in finding out if what I am doing is correct because the convergence stops at $0.00009$ instead of $0$.

Comment: that is a machine precision limitation.

Comment: Well, define "correct". This gives you an approximation with a certain number of significant digits. Switching to a variant may give you a better one. What is 'correct' and what is not?

Comment: I am not sure what i do is correct because i have to prove that newton-raphson used on f to find the root 0 converges linearly, yet in my octave script the algorithm converges at 0.00009 in 31 steps instead of 0 in the long run. So i dont know how to prove that it converges linearly to 0 when it doesn't even converge to 0.

Comment: Is there some reason that you cannot differeniate the polynomial, enough to reduce the multiplicity to one? Presumably, that is easier to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that using the `expm1` function would give you a better result.

Computing $e^x -1$ with the trivial formula in machine precision gives you only limited accuracy for small inputs: the fundamental reason is that there are only "few" floating point numbers around 1, and when you first compute $e^x$ the machine has to approximate your result to the closest floating point number. For instance, the next number after $1$ is $1+2^{-52}$, so every number in $[1, 1+2^{-52}]$ has to be replaced with one of the two extremes. So computing, for instance, $e^{2^{-100}} \approx 1 + 2^{-100}$ and then subtracting 1 results in a huge (relative) error.

Hence there is the need for a separate library function that computes $e^x-1$ natively and is accurate also for small inputs (it can be implemented using a Taylor expansion for small inputs, for instance). Hence `expm1`, which is in most programming languages. (The IEEE floating point standard "recommends" to include it in its implementations.)

(Similarly, there is `log1p` to compute $\log(1+x)$. These functions are very handy when working with very small probabilities in log space, for instance.)

In any case, if you *know* that your function has a multiple zero, there is no reason not to use a Newton variant designed for multiple zeros.

Comment: Just to note that `expm1` and `log1p` were mandated in the 1999 revision of the C standard, so are almost universally available in mathematical software.